# My bash script checking prime numbers works not correct?

Tags: bash, macos, shell

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#for checking whether given number is prime or not

#typeset -i NUMBER
NUMBER=$1

if (( $NUMBER <= 1 ));then
 echo "A prime number must be greater than 1!"
  exit 0
fi

if (( $NUMBER == 2 || $NUMBER == 3 ));then
  echo "$NUMBER is a PRIME number."
  exit 0
fi

check=$(((($NUMBER**2)+17)%12))
if (( $check == 6 ));then
   echo "$NUMBER is a PRIME number."
else
   echo "$NUMBER is not a PRIME number."
fi

exit 0
```

Generally it works but look at this:

```
./prime2  12345765498743607656323978968565589876654541139797868554123589679789867896789789789789789789897789

A prime number must be greater than 1!
```

It seems that the number to proof will not be interpret in the right way.
Any clue ?

Comment: The number is way beyond the allowed integer in the Bourne shell. Bash tries to truancate numbers beyond `(2^31)-1` or `(2^63)-1`, depending on your architecture

Comment: Your prime number checker doesn't work. Consider _n_ = 25. Your formula takes 25 ** 2, which is 625, adds 17 to get 642, and takes the modulus with 12, which is 6, so you report that 25 = 5 * 5 is prime, which is incorrect.

Comment: @user448810 Correct....i must review my code !   Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because of integer overflow arising out of the maximum positive integer your system could support. The numbers beyond `(2^31)-1` or `(2^63)-1` on `32-bit` and `64-bit` start having negative values due to this reason.

Check the behaviour on my Mac, a `64-bit` machine

```
dudeOnMac: ~$ uname -a
Darwin dudeOnMac 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Sun Sep 25 22:07:15 PDT 2016; root:xnu-2782.50.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

dudeOnMac: ~$ ((number=(2**63)-1)); echo $number
9223372036854775807
dudeOnMac: ~$ ((number++)); echo $number
-9223372036854775808
```

and for the weird number you have provided in your input

```
dudeOnMac: ~$ number=12345765498743607656323978968565589876654541139797868554123589679789867896789789789789789789897789
```

Look at what happens when I try to increment it,

```
dudeOnMac: ~$ ((number++)); echo $number
-398770938935753666
```

So the condition `if (( $NUMBER <= 1 ))` in your script will obviously be `true` in your script.

You can of course check your script's functionality upto the max allowed integer values depending upon your system architecture.

Comment: Hey Inian, thank you very much for your explanation ! I realize it is not possible to check so high numbers are prime or not on normal 64bit Linux machines. Or is it a way to do this ?

Comment: @RELiABLE: You can check upto the maximum allowed number depending upon your architecture. e.g. on a `64-bit` machine `9223372036854775807`

Comment: Ok....but look, this works on my 64bit maschine: ./prime2 885685678978956689568967497689678954768978977867868767866
885685678978956689568967497689678954768978977867868767866 is not a PRIME number.

Comment: @RELiABLE: Am not sure how you can verify it though :) may be try looking up online for that number and that says it is not prime, your logic might actually be right! Good luck

Comment: @RELiABLE: On other note, remember `885685678978956689568967497689678954768978977867868767866` is not the actual number because it is well beyond the max digit in your `64-bit` machine, a positive number on your script is due to the overflown value which is unpredicted. Don't take it for granted that your script worked for such large number. `number=885685678978956689568967497689678954768978977867868767866;((number++)); echo $number
5274778760553006715`